# An easy jquery code I am missing somehow as a jquery novice

Tags: jquery

How to add a div after all dd tags through jquery ?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('dd').xyz('<div class="clear"></div>'); // what will be this xyz function
});
```

I have the following HTML structure -

```
<dl>
    <dt>A</dt>
    <dd>AA</dd>
    <dt>B</dt>
    <dd>BB</dd>
</dl>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be like - `$('<div class="clear" />').insertAfter('dd');`

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('dd').after('<div class="clear"></div>');
});
```

Here is example, I've created jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/VWYf4/

Answer (score 1):

if you want to add `div` after each `dd` tag, please try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('dd').each(function(){    
     $(this).after('<div class="clear"></div>');
   });
});
```

check fiddle here

http://jsfiddle.net/VHKu5/